# Simple package with function in Oracle is in invalid state

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm reading about packages and I wanted to start with creating a new one that has one function that returns some number. I did something like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE KP_XYZ_TEST_SQL AS
  FUNCTION CONTAINS() RETURN NUMBER;
END KP_XYZ_TEST_SQL;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY KP_XYZ_TEST_SQL AS
  FUNCTION CONTAINS() RETURN NUMBER AS
  BEGIN

   RETURN 1;

  END CONTAINS;
END KP_XYZ_TEST_SQL;
```

Everything seemed to be executed fine and both the package and package body have been created. But when I try to execute `CONTAINS()` I get an error: `ORA-06576: Package or function KP_XYZ_TEST_SQL is in invalid state`.

This is how I try to execute my function:

```
SELECT KP_XYZ_TEST_SQL.CONTAINS() FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE KP_XYZ_TEST_SQL AS
  FUNCTION CONTAINS RETURN NUMBER;
END KP_XYZ_TEST_SQL;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY KP_XYZ_TEST_SQL AS
  FUNCTION CONTAINS RETURN NUMBER AS
  BEGIN

   RETURN 1;

  END CONTAINS;
END KP_XYZ_TEST_SQL;
```

You should not use "()" after function name if function contains no parameters.

Comment: It doesn't work. But I found a problem... I was adding a package before its body. When I did it inversely, everything started working...

Comment: No, it should work. The only thing to do is execute the specification part first and only after it executed, to execute the body part, not everything together. Also, if you add the body before the package specification you will get 'cannot compile body without specification' error for sure. The brackets after the function name will not work too.

Comment: I have edited the answer, so the whole script can be executed at once.